# (Python) Text widget line numbers

Tags: python, tkinter

I have some code working that displays line numbers along the left side of a text widget. For the most part, it works well, but there are a couple of issues that I need some pointers on how to fix.

I have posted the code below.

Here is a link to a test file with 200 lines (each line is numbered).

[test file here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j2mx7bsz064twhn/line_test.py?dl=0)

Issues:

(1) You can mouse wheel (scroll) up and down the file. However, this causes the line numbers to get out of sync with the text widget line numbers. If someone can point me in the right direction to look at, I probably can figure it out and fix it.

(2) The PgDn/PgUp keys have a similar effect. I can hit PgDn a few times and notice the Text widget lines get out of sync with the line numbers, as well as losing their horizontal alignment. Again, if someone can point me in the right direction to look at, I'm sure I can figure out what's happening in the code and fix it.

```
from tkinter import *
 
class LineNumbers(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, text_widget, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
 
        self.text_widget = text_widget
        self.text_widget.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.on_key_release)
        self.text_widget.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_key_release)
        self.text_widget.bind('<MouseWheel>', self.on_key_release)
 
        self.insert(1.0, '1')
        self.configure(state='disabled')
 
    def on_key_release(self, event=None):
        p, q = self.text_widget.index("@0,0").split('.')
        p = int(p)
        final_index = str(self.text_widget.index(END))
        num_of_lines = final_index.split('.')[0]
        line_numbers_string = "\n".join(str(p + no) for no in range(int(num_of_lines)))
        width = len(str(num_of_lines))
 
        self.configure(state='normal', width=width)
        self.delete(1.0, END)
        self.insert(1.0, line_numbers_string)
        self.configure(state='disabled')
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = Tk()
    win.title("Line Numbers Test")
    win.geometry("800x600+1000+300")
 
    txt = Text(win)
    ln = LineNumbers(win, txt, width=2)
 
    f = open("line_test.txt", 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        txt.insert(END, line)
    f.close()
 
    ln.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
    txt.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
    txt.focus()
    win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 0):

```
class LineNumbers(Text):
    def __init__(self, master, text_widget, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.busy = False
        self.master = master
        self.text_widget = text_widget
        self.text_widget.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.on_key_release)
        self.text_widget.bind('<FocusIn>', self.on_key_release)
        self.text_widget.bind('<MouseWheel>',  self.on_mousew)
        self.text_widget.bind('<Button-4>',  self.on_mousew)
        self.text_widget.bind('<Button-5>',  self.on_mousew)

        self.insert(1.0, '1')
        self.configure(state='disabled')

    def on_mousew(self, event=None):
            self.after( 50, self.bogus)

    def on_key_release(self, event=None):
            self.after( 50, self.bogus)
            return "break"

    def bogus( self):
        self.text_widget.update()
        p, q = self.text_widget.index("@0,0").split('.')
        np = int(p)
        self.text_widget.see(  "@" + str( np+1) + ","+ q)
        final_index = str(self.text_widget.index(END))
        num_of_lines = final_index.split('.')[0]
        line_numbers_string = "\n".join( str(np+no) for no in range(0, int(num_of_lines)))
        width = len(str(num_of_lines))

        self.configure(state='normal', width=width)
        self.delete(1.0, END)
        self.insert(1.0, line_numbers_string)
        self.configure(state='disabled')
```